# Запустить программу CreateProcess

Tags: c++, c, winapi

Как запустить консольную программу сделанную в Visual Studio через CreateProcess? Ошибок не выскакивает, но программа не запускается.

```
#include <Windows.h>
#include <iostream>
#include <tchar.h>
using namespace std;


int main() {
    HANDLE hProcess;
    HANDLE hThread;
    STARTUPINFO si;
    PROCESS_INFORMATION pi;
    ZeroMemory(&si, sizeof(si));
    ZeroMemory(&pi, sizeof(pi));
    CreateProcess(L"C:\ConsoleApplication2\Debug\ConsoleApplication2.exe",
        NULL, NULL, NULL, FALSE, 0, NULL, NULL, &si, &pi);
    cout << "GetProcessID -> " << GetProcessId(pi.hProcess) << endl;
    system("PAUSE");
    return 0;
}
```

Comment: Cмотрите что вернуло CreateProcess, а потом GetLastError.

Comment: Поле cb в переменной si установите в корректное значение.

Comment: @nick_n_a PROCESS_INFORMATION же заполняется внутри CreateProcess. В MSDN по крайней мере этот параметр обозначен как Out...

Comment: @ВладимирМартьянов да, я не заметил ZeroMemory, я бы делал так `STARTUPINFO si  = {0,}` а лучше так `STARTUPINFO si  = {sizeof(si),0,}` Хотя что возвращает  cout  - не написано.

Answer (score 2):

Слэши в пути к исполняемому файлу должны быть двойные. Иначе - у вас путь неправильный.

Comment: это вторая ошибка

Answer (score 1):

Поле cb в переменной si установите в корректное значение для начала.

Comment: Почему вызывая функцию не посмотреть что она вернула, тут функция вернула false, в MSDN сказано смотрите GetLastError - она вернула бы одну ошибку, потом другую и всё. Некорректную si правда сложно догадаться.

Comment: @nick_n_a вот уж не знаю почему автор код возврата не смотрит... Две явных ошибки нашли, а дальше уже надо смотреть код возврата и вот это вот все...